# How to write SQL query to read most recent timestamps (using window function)?

Tags: sql, window-functions, azure-data-lake, delta-lake

I have a table in my database that has rows inserted without updating old ones. That leads to having records with same ID but diffrent timestamps. How to write SQL query that uses window function to read rows with distinct IDs and most recent timestamps?

Comment: Tag your DBMS to the question. You may consider `row_number()` function as a possible solution if your DBMS supports it.

Comment: A regular GROUP BY could perhaps also work? A [mcve] would make things clearer. Also add a tag for the dbms used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with base as (
select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by timestamp desc) as rn from table
)
select * except(rn) from base
where rn = 1
```